# Class definition private

Tags: java, class, extends

I'm new at java and I'm trying to figure out what it means to have

```
private SecondClass FirstClass
```

The SecondClass is defined as

```
protected static class SecondClass extends FirstClass
```

Comment: Is the first code section a field definition? If so, that means you have a private instance of the SecondClass type named "FirstCalss".

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the FirstClass has the same name as the extended class matters?

Comment: The first code is a field definition

Comment: No it does not matter at all. If that is a field definition you are naming an instance variable which does not matter that there is a class of the same name. The only instance it would matter is if the variable name overrides a java keyword.

Comment: No a problem. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Remember the naming convention: the first letter of a class name should be uppercase, while the first letter of a variable should be lowercase